# Deploy de aplicações Node

Tags: node.js

Olá estou começando a estudar node e me surgiu uma dúvida, como é feita o deploy de uma aplicação em node?

Hoje eu trabalho em uma empresa como desenvolvedor e hospedamos nossa aplicação em um servidor no Azure e usamos IIS como servidor web. No caso do Node como eu faria? deveria fazer uma integração com o IIS ou instalo um Linux e integro ele no apache?

Desculpe a ignorância e que eu realmente não faço ideia =P

Desde já agradeço pessoal !